# Errors in changing the n_jobs of LinearRegression

Tags: python, machine-learning, anaconda, data-mining, linear-regression

When I use the `LinearRegression classifier`, I changed the `n_jobs` to `-1,1,9,10`. When the parameter is `-1` and `10`, it worked well. But when it came to `1` and `9`, it showed this:

```
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',)).
```

So what's the problem here? And why if I change the `n_jobs`, it has different accuracy?

Comment: The current form of this question is very unclear. Please elaborate a bit more about the library you are using, the dataset, the full stack of error, what was working and whats not, etc.

Comment: Well, I tried just now. It was fine now. Though I didn't know what happened. I used the LinearRegression in sklearn. Anyway, thanks a lot!